# Tailwind CSS custom width and height not working, although the same values can be applied using straight CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind CSS in React and I am trying to set a width of 500px for my images div. But the width of the div does not increase more than 300px.

[image: width set to 300px]

```
<div className="flex flex-row gap-4 mb-12">

    <div className='images px-6 basis-0'>

        <div className=' img bg-primary mb-4 w-[300px] h-[300px]'>
        </div>

        <div className=' img bg-primary mb-4 w-[300px] h-[300px]'>
        </div>

        <div className=' img bg-primary mb-4 w-[300px] h-[300px]'>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div className='product_info basis-0'>
        ...
    </div>

</div>
```

When I change the width in the custom classes from 300px to 500px the boxes just disappear:

[image]

If I manually adjust the width and height using CSS, it works fine.

```
.img{
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

[image]

I don't understand what is causing this issue :(

Comment: Are you rebuilding your CSS after changing the value from `w-[300px]` to `w-[500px]`? These will generate different CSS rules in the Tailwind output, so if you try to change the pixel value directly in the DOM (using the dev tools) or in your code without regenerating the CSS, no CSS rule will be available and your page will act like you don't have a setting for the width.

Comment: I'm experiencing something very similar. I can only set one specific height and it works, if I change it to some other value, the `<div>` height just collapses to the height of the content. Did you ever find a solution without using plain CSS?

Comment: @EdLucas How do you "rebuild" the CSS? When something doesn't work as expected, I usually first try to clean my React project (in my case it's actually Gatsby, so I do `gatsby clean`) and then I build the project again.

Comment: @ewerspej If you follow the installation instructions for Tailwind CSS under Gatsby, the CSS should automatically be regenerated when you save a related file. See: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/gatsby

Comment: @EdLucas Exactly, that was my thinking. Based on your comment, it sounded like there was some other trick.

Comment: @ewerspej Other platforms don't hot reload Tailwind styles (e.g. Stencil.js), so I was being general in my initial comment.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar issue and I managed to fix it by including the directory of my custom components in the ***tailwind.config.js*** file:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  important: true,
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./src/sections/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  plugins: [],
}
```

Now, for me setting the height for `<div>` elements works fine, e.g.:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Section from "../components/section";

const AboutSection = () => {
  return (
    <Section id="about">
      <div className="m-0 flex h-[384px] w-full flex-col p-0 md:h-[512px] lg:h-[640px] xl:h-[768px]">
        <h1>About Me</h1>
      </div>
    </Section>
  );
};

export default AboutSection;
```

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into a similar problem a while back which I solved. You can try this code maybe it will solve it.

```
<div className='bg-primary mb-4 w-[300px] h-[300px] block'>
</div>

<div className='bg-primary mb-4 w-[300px] h-[300px] block'>
</div>

<div className='bg-primary mb-4 w-[300px] h-[300px] block'>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide more detail on why this works

Answer (score -1):

I just started learning tailwind, but it should be something like this when referring to height and width:

```html
<div class="w-96 ..."></div>
```

Here is a [reference](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width).

In the case of React's inline styling it would be:

```html
<div className="w-96 ..."></div>
```

Also with the div not changing you have the basis set at 0, when it should be more than that, I use the x/12 option as it breaks it down into a 12 column format for sizing. So maybe try 6/12 and have your second container set to the difference (6/12), thats if you want it even:

```html
<div className="flex flex-row gap-4 mb-12">

    <div className='images px-6 basis-6/12'>

        <div className=' img bg-primary mb-4 w-[300px] h-[300px]'>
        </div>

        <div className=' img bg-primary mb-4 w-[300px] h-[300px]'>
        </div>

        <div className=' img bg-primary mb-4 w-[300px] h-[300px]'>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div className='product_info basis-6/12'>
        ...
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is a reference for [basis](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-basis).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using those Arbitrary values, you can customize your theme by simply doing

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      width: {
        '76': '18.75rem',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That way you can use it everywhere on your code.
You can also add them to an external CSS file.

Always avoid using Arbitrary values.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

In a tailwind writing a format like "w-[300px] h-[300px]" will most likely be unreadable if done repeatedly. Therefore, I think you can customize the width and height in the tailwind.config.js file.

So you can resize and customize it in the tailwind.config.js file, and then we can call it like tailwind as usual.

[Example for custom width:](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width)
Note: I converted the size of the pixels to REM, where 300 pixels = 18.75 REM.

```
module.exports = {
   theme: {
     extend: {
       widths: {
         '76': '18.75rem',
       }
     }
   }
}
```

[Custom example for height:](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height)
Note: I converted the size of the pixels to REM, where 300 pixels = 18.75 REM.

```
module.exports = {
   theme: {
     extend: {
       height: {
         '76': '18.75rem',
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: useful, good job....

Comment: It's theme property, not themes